# If statement returns undefined when checking if an array doesn't contain a word

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement

I'm trying to log each name in the array except for the users, _id, etc. Doing `if(!word === "users")` works and logs the user entry as I would expect. I'm probably overlooking something trivial and apologize in advance. Thank you.

```
let arr = ["noun","nounoffensive","nounvulgar","adjective","verb","verbinformal","conjunction","exclamation","users","_id","word","createdAt","updatedAt","__v"]

arr.forEach((word)=>{
    if(!word === "users" || "_id" || "word" || "createdAt" || "updatedAt"){
        console.log(word)
    };
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `if` statement is incorrect. You are missing `word ===` for other comparison and `!` should be there for entire expression.

```js
let arr = ["noun","nounoffensive","nounvulgar","adjective","verb","verbinformal","conjunction","exclamation","users","_id","word","createdAt","updatedAt","__v"]

arr.forEach((word)=>{
    if(!(word === "users" || word === "_id" || word === "word" || word === "createdAt" || word === "updatedAt")){
        console.log(word)
    };
});
```

The alternative approach could also be to create a array, say, `let notInArray = ["users", "_id", "word", "createdAt", "updatedAt"];` that contains the word you want to exclude:

```js
let arr = ["noun","nounoffensive","nounvulgar","adjective","verb","verbinformal","conjunction","exclamation","users","_id","word","createdAt","updatedAt","__v"]

let notInArray = ["users", "_id", "word", "createdAt", "updatedAt"];
arr.forEach((word)=>{
  if(notInArray.indexOf(word) === -1){
    console.log(word)
  };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use

`if(!word === "users" || "_id" || "word" || "createdAt" || "updatedAt")`

as if statement.

You could use an array to check if it is inside:

```js
let arr = ["noun","nounoffensive","nounvulgar","adjective","verb","verbinformal","conjunction","exclamation","users","_id","word","createdAt","updatedAt","__v"]
const words2find = ['users', '_id', 'word', 'createdAt', 'updatedAt'];

arr.forEach((word)=>{
    if(words2find.indexOf(word) < 0){
        console.log(word)
    };
});
```

Comment: You should be more precise if you don't want to mislead future readers. We can totally use things like this as an if statement. It's valid javascript code. But it's just not what the OP thought it would do. By the way this test is always `true`

Comment: I̶ ̶w̶o̶u̶l̶d̶n̶'̶t̶ ̶s̶a̶y̶ ̶t̶h̶i̶s̶ ̶i̶s̶ ̶v̶a̶l̶i̶d̶  - nvm, I see what you're saying.

Comment: yes i know we both know ;) but a beginner could be puzzled here, nothing really important though